# build a "double divergent" axis title in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to build an axis title with a string left-aligned and a string right aligned.

I've tried using css styles for the title text property but it does not work:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        title: {
            text: '<span id=xleft style="width:50%;text-align:left;">here is left</span><span id=xright style="width:50%;text-align:right;">here is right</span>'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

The image below shows the output of the above code (http://jsfiddle.net/rfvgegkk/) while the arrows indicate the desired result:

[image]

Is there any other solution or workaround? 
(The best would be that it can be replicated also for a vertical y-axis title)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Renderer.text](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.text) to achieve desired result

```
function(chart) { // on complete
  chart.renderer.text('Series 1', 60, 350)
    .attr({

    })
    .css({
      color: '#4572A7',
      fontSize: '16px'
    })
    .add();
  chart.renderer.text('Series 2', chart.plotSizeX, 350)
    .attr({

    })
    .css({
      color: '#4572A7',
      fontSize: '16px'
    })
    .add();
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deu3g8c1/)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to achieve the desired result using two bands on the y-axis and positioning them at the minimum y-axis value: http://jsfiddle.net/rfvgegkk/2/. If needed, the same trick holds for the other axis.

```
yAxis: {
    plotLines: [{
        width: 0,
        value: 0,
        label: {
            text: 'here is right',
            align: 'right',
            x: -10,
            y: 26
        }
    },{
        width: 0,
        value: 0,
        label: {
            text: 'here is left',
            align: 'left',
            x: -10,
            y: 26
        }
    }
    ]
```

Comment: but still it is overlapping with labels

Comment: Increase band y value.

Comment: You can increase y parameter to avoid overlapping.